# Why length decreases after using replace?

Tags: java

I have a string `"(3+3)*(4-2)(+(+("`.In order  to split it where `(` is present,I hadfirst replaced the given string using replace method to `+` Then I wanted to find the length of the new array.In the given string there are 5 `(` so the length of the array should be 5 but it gives me 2.May i know why this occurs.

```
String x =String x ="(3+3)*(4-2)(((";
    String y=x.replace("(", "_");
    String z[]=y.split("_");

    System.out.println(y);

    System.out.println("length  "+z.length);
```

the output is

```
_3+3)*_4-2)___
```

length  3

**EDIT**

I made a mistake.As I was posting a part of my code so made some mistake.Please see the updated code

Comment: _ is not -. these are 2 different symbols

Comment: replace value is _ by split value is -

Comment: well, you split around the "-" char, not the "_" char.

Comment: If you'd print out z[0] you'd find the issue.

Comment: @njzk2 You should have posted it as answer.

Comment: @njzk2 I made a mistake in posting the real code,please see the new one

Comment: @Matthias I made a mistake in posting the real code,please see the new one

Comment: because there is no data in between the previous _ to next _

Comment: if any value in between the two _ that will be stored into the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you mean to say you want to split by ("_") but you have written

`String z[]=y.split("-");`

So it will split by `-` not `_`

so two parts in array will be

`_3+3)*_4`

and

`2)_+_+_`

**EDIT:**

After `String z[]=y.split("_");`, length you're getting is `3` which is absolutely right. as shown below:

-->(blank)   `firstElement`

_ `(split on first _ )`

--> 3+3)*     `secondElement`

_ `(split on second_ )`

-->4-2)    `thirdElement`

Comment: I made a mistake in posting the real code,please see the new one

Comment: There were problem some where else and i thought my error is in this part.but still I should thank you for taking pain in finding an explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
String z[]=y.split("_");
```

instead of

```
String z[]=y.split("-");
```

Try this,

```
    String x = "____";
    String z[] = x.split("_");
    System.out.println("length  " + z.length);
```

output `length 0`

Answer (score 1):

you should not split with the argument "-". use "_" instead!

Answer (score 0):

```
String z[]=y.split("-");
z[0] = "_3+3)*_4";
z[1] = "2)_+_+_";
```

So `z.length == 2`. I don't see any flaw here, unless you wanted to split by `_`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String x ="(3+3)*(4-2)(+(+(";
            ____________________________________
String x-->|        (3+3)*(4-2)(((              | 
           |____________________________________|  
String y=x.replace("(", "_");
            ____________________________________
String y-->|        _3+3)*_4-2)___              | 
           |____________________________________|
```

and 
after `String z[]=y.split("-");`

```
z[0]----->3+3)*

z[1]----->4-2)
```

while `"___".split("_")` evaluates null strings.

So the length of `z[]` is 2